# FreeNAS NUT Slave and not master?

Tags: ups, truenas, nut

I have 2x FreeNAS servers and one UPS.

The First FreeNAS server has the NUT stuff configured, running and working just fine.

Is there a way to configure my second freeNAS server to be a slave to the first FreeNAS server like I can do with other linux machines?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original poster may have found an answer by now, but just for the sake of others who visit this thread, NUT master/slave is merely a matter of configuration. Install NUT per the appropriate OS then configure one, and only one, machine to the master. The others will be set as slaves and provided the ip address of the master.

Check out this link: http://www.networkupstools.org/

Answer (score 1):

The FreeNAS GUI have the option of running nut as master or slave, so it should be no problem setting it up.

The problem comes when you have multiple (redundant) UPS'es, the GUI does not handle that well.

You could configure nut yourself, and either chflags schg /etc/local/nut/* to keep the freenas gui to mess with the config files. 
Or change nut_prefix to /usr/local.myown in /etc/rc.conf.local and have the nut config files in /usr/local.myown/nut

As usual, the GUI is useful and easy, but if you really want to do serious stuff, you must use CLI.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know this is not exactly possible..

You can however..

Continuously rsync the boxes together ( i dont believe FreeNas does any DRDB / block level replication)

To failover, you will need something like heartbeat or a proxy externally
FreeNas is a great product, but is not exactly supporting conventional/proprietary cluster services.. ( You might need to make your own)

You could also consider doing this from the application side, depending on what your actually using freeNAS for.. I believe with running something like VM or the windows equivalent you can

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Arenstar, I think you did not read or understand my question properly. I am not talking about master/slave of DATA, I am talking about Master Slave of NUT which is a utility to manage your battery backup.  One server is normally the battery backup Master and has the UPS plugged into it (usb or serial) then the other machines (slaves) are told to shut down by the Master if the ups goes on battery.

Comment: Ahh..  can you please rephrase the question???
Cause from what you wrote it sounds like you want redundancy if a server was to absolutely fail..

Comment: it is actually pretty clear, in the subject I specify NUT and in the question I specify one UPS and one NUT Master and one NUT slave. Not sure how much clearer you want it to be.